# Mysql query is really slow. How do I increase the speed of the query?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, mysql-workbench

I want to the latest results for my patients. The following sql returns 69,000 results after **87 seconds** in mysqlworkbench. I have made both 'date' and 'patientid' columns as index.

```
select Max(date) as MaxDate, PatientID 
from assessment
group by PatientID
```

I think my table has approximately 440,000 in total. Is it because that my table is 'large'?

Is there a way to increase the speed of this query, because I will have to embed this query inside other queries. For example like below:

```
select aa.patientID, assessment.Date, assessment.result
from assessemnt
inner join
    (select Max(date) as MaxDate, PatientID 
    from assessment
    group by PatientID) as aa
on aa.patientID = assessment.patientID and aa.MaxDate = assessment.Date
```

The above will give me the latest assessment results for each patient. Then I will also embed this piece of code to do other stuff... So I really need to speed up things. Anyone can help?

Comment: post your related table structure code.

Comment: And post result of `EXPLAIN` on Your data.

Comment: @RomanHocke I know I am being stupid, but I can't seem to find the 'EXPLAIN' in mysqlworkbench.....

Comment: You are not being stupid :-) Just put `EXPLAIN` before Your SQL query. Like `EXPLAIN SELECT ... FROM ...`.

Comment: @RomanHocke thanks a lot. What should I look at in the explain? I noticed that today both queries now become extreme fast. Probably because I used the composite index as Gordon suggested? What should I pay attention in the explain, the index?

Comment: `EXPLAIN` shows you MySQL's execution plan - what it needs to do to perform Your query. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain-output.html for details. Maybe You see that the query now uses the new index etc. You may compare execution plans with and without the index to see differences etc.

Comment: Can there be two `results` on a single `date`?  If so, do you want it to show both, as your query is currently coded?

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if this version would have better performance with the right indexes:

```
select a.patientID, a.Date, a.result
from assessemnt a
where a.date = (select aa.date
                from assessment aa
                where aa.patientID = a.patientID
                order by aa.date desc
                limit 1
               );
```

Then you want an index on `assessment(patientID, date)`.

EDIT:

Another approach uses an index on `assessment(patient_id, date, result)`:

```
select a.*
from (select a.patient_id, a.date, a.result,
             (@rn := if(@p = a.patient_id, @rn + 1,
                        if(@p := a.patient_id, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from assessment a cross join
          (select @p := -1, @rn := 0) params
      order by patient_id desc, date desc
     ) a
where rn = 1;
```

Comment: Hmm thats an interesting approach, I must remember that, sort of sneek up on it from behind so to speak.

Comment: A stupid question, how do we define index? In this case, what's difference between making 2 indexes for column 'date' and 'patientID' seperate and making 1 index using the 2 columns together?

Comment: @UweAllner ???? What do you mean? I wasn't meant to insult anybody. I was just asking if there is difference between defining the index on 2 columns separately and defining them together as one. I truly dont know.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I just tried your script. It does perform a bit faster than mine but it still took 43.462 seconds to run. (Mine took 66.332 seconds). I wonder if there is any other ways to improve this query??? :(

Comment: @wildcolor . . . There is a big difference between two indexes on two separate columns and a single composite index on two columns.  As specified in this answer, composite indexes are the better choice.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks again. So based on what criteria do we use two separate index or one composite index? I know I should probably do a search myself first

Comment: @wildcolor . . . The answer clearly recommends composite indexes.

Comment: The second query cannot use the index effectively -- it is mixing `ASC` and `DESC`.  This would work better: `order by patient_id DESC, date desc`.  Then reorder things in the outer query, if desired.

Comment: @RickJames . . . Good catch.  I changed the index to be descending on the date.

Comment: That does not work.  `DESC` is _ignored_ in defining an index.  (A MySQL 'deficiency' that is noted in the manual.)